# Combination of columns in where condition

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a clarification in SQL where condition, how do I use multiple columns combination in where conditions?

For example:

```
select *
from employees
where employee_firstName+employee_lastName = @emp_FirstName+@emp_LastName
```

I want the combination of the two parameters together.

I am using Sybase. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test it, but should work faster:

```
select *
from employees
where employee_firstName = @emp_FirstName
  and employee_lastName  = @emp_LastName
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use concatenation operator, as described here:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks248.htm

```
select *
from employees
where (employee_firstName+employee_lastName) = (@emp_FirstName+@emp_LastName)
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander and maialithar, Its worked for me, i tried with (employee_FirstName+employee_LastName) = (@emp_FirstName+@emp_LastName) .. Working Fine .. Thanks realy helpful for me!!!!! guys..

Comment: Not only this is non-sargable, but it can also return unexpected rows. For instance, if you searched for `Mariah Olbert`, you might additionally get `Maria Holbert`, and vice versa.